# Python socket - smtp program hangs after asking for username

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, python-sockets

So I'm working on the smtp socket program. I'm using gmail smtp. I'm facing problem in authentication as my code hangs after server asks me for the username. following is my authentication code.

```
auth = 'AUTH LOGIN\r\n'
clientSocketSSL.send(auth.encode())
recv1 = clientSocketSSL.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '334':
   print('334 reply not received from server')

username = base64.b64encode(b'******@gmail.com\r\n')
clientSocketSSL.send(username)
recv1 = clientSocketSSL.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '334':
   print('334 reply not received from server')

password = base64.b64encode(b'*******\r\n')
clientSocketSSL.send(password)
recv1 = clientSocketSSL.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '235':
   print('235 reply not received from server')
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the `\r\n` in the string that you encode with base 64. It needs to be sent after the base64-encoded username or password.

```
username = base64.b64encode(b'******@gmail.com\r\n')
clientSocketSSL.send((username + '\r\n'));
```